# Why does everyone uses "the dream home/the dream home" instead of "the dreaming home"?

Tags: word-choice, grammar

This question was suddenly popped out in my head. I wonder if "dream" is a noun and verb (followed by the definition in my dictionary (hope it has a quality enough) ) why it is widely used as "the dream house/home" not "the dreaming house/home" because dreaming is an adjective or be like that just because it is a compound noun?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I have never heard the term "dreaming home", here in the US.  And keep in mind that "dream" as an adjective is well-established.  Dream vacation, dream date, dream job.

Comment: Because (1) house and home can't dream and (2) their function or purpose is not to dream. "Sleeping bag" is used because the bag is used when you sleep. You can Google "noun adjunct" or "attributive noun".

Answer (score 2):

"Dream" is indeed a noun used as a modifier: what kind of home? a dream home, one that might figure in your dreams.

"A dreaming home" (which does not exist as a set expression) would mean something different.

Comment: Specifically, "a dreaming home" is a home that is currently dreaming.

Comment: @Jessa: that's one possible interpretation. It could also mean "A home for dreaming in" - with "dreaming" a verbal noun (gerund) used as a modifer, like "walking stick".